# Postgres container doesn't start

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm sorry for the noob question.
I try to run a PostgreSQL database in a container for tests.
The commands:

```
docker create --name container-name -p 5432:5432 postgres
docker start container-name
```

Both commands work but when I check with

```
docker ps -a
```

It says, that the container stopped right after the start with exit code 1.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Does `docker logs container-name` say anything?  I might just run `docker run` rather than splitting `docker create` and `docker start`, but it shouldn't make a difference here.

Comment: I didn't know about the command `docker logs container-name`. I can solve it now myself! I'll write the answer as a separate answer. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @David Maze for your comment.
With `docker logs container-name` I was able to find out, that I got a way more detailed error message.
It says:

> Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not
> specified.
> You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD for the superuser. Use
> "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set it in "docker run".
> You may also use POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust to allow all connections without a password. This is *not* recommended. See
> PostgreSQL
> documentation about "trust":
> [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html%60)

This makes it clear for me, that I have to somehow preconfigure the container before I can start it.